# What slows down the Reasoner the most in Protege 5?

Tags: owl, protege, reasoner

My ontology is 3000 axioms for now but I have a lot of individuals that must be there in the future.
Reasoner [image]slows around 10 minutes for reasoning on it. I think this is not normal and I am trying to make it better and solve it somehow. May be I have a lot of labels, if it's a propblematic.

Pellet infers really fast - may be 5 sec.

What is the real difference between this two Reasoners? Are thay interchangeable.

*Will be really happy on all your comments. Thank you!*

Comment: there is no answer to this. Besides the number of axioms, the type of axioms are important. And sometimes even less axioms are worse. Pellet vs. HermiT is Tableau vs. Hyper-Tableau - sometimes one is "better", sometimes the other - so again, "it depends"

Comment: Latest version compatible with protégé is 1.4.5.456, you can try updating to it (jar available on Maven Central) to see if it makes a difference. Otherwise, locating the reasons for slow performance is a complex task. If you can share the ontology, people might help - without that it would be very hard to make suggestions.